# Unpack variadic template arguments into variadic inherited classes

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, crtp

I have simple 3 classes, two of them inherite virtually:

```cpp
struct A
{

};

struct B : virtual A
{
    B(int, int) { }
};

struct C : virtual A
{
    C(int) { }
};
```

Now I want to have a class which inherit multiple classes and initialize them via constructor arguments:

```cpp
template<typename... Ts>
struct D : public Ts...
{
    template<typename... Args>
    D(Args... args) : A{ }, Ts{ args }...
    {

    }
};
```

Trying to use it:

```cpp
D<B, C>{1, 2, 3};
```

It doesn't compile due to errors:

`Ts the number of elements in this pack expansion does not match the number of elements in args`.

`B no appropriate default constructor available`

`C no appropriate default constructor available`

Generally it works pretty well when constructor of class `B` takes only single parameter (the same number of parameters as class `C`).

Comment: Can't you just specify the arguments in the call? `D<B, C>{B{1, 2}, 3};` works for me.

Comment: This `Ts{ args }...` will expand both packs together, into `B{1}, C{2}, /*err*/{3}` - The compiler has no way to know how you want to group the arguments.

Comment: You could feasibly pass tuples as argument bundles for each class. Something like this https://wandbox.org/permlink/cqN9QxxJe7q8dBJG

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica: according to [Pack Expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) Ts{args}... can be expanded only if Ts and args have the same number of elements. Otherwise it's an error.
Moreover, in D<A,B,C>{1,2,3} it would be expanded as A{1,2,3}, B{1,2,3}, C{1,2,3},

Comment: @Dharmesh946 - What do you reckon `/*err*/` is? And no, `B{1,2,3}` will never happen. You have a serious misunderstanding. Perhaps confusing it with `Ts{args...}...`

Comment: I don't speak of the actual class in the example but of the way Ts{args}... may be expanded. But indeed It seem's that I didn't understood cppref as this example shows: https://godbolt.org/z/4zErszdWY

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here: `D<B, C>{1, 2, 3};`. You have declared an instance `B` & `C` but the compiler doesn't understand how to pack the values `{1, 2, 3}`. So you need to write explicitly like this: `D<B, C> obj{B{1, 2}, C{3}};`.